# Exact compare $(window).height() value with particular value of scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

First I am getting $(window).height() and this height I want to compare with the particular value of scroll.

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();
        console.log("window height---> " +windowHeight);
        console.log("scroll value----> "+scroll);

        if (scroll == windowHeight) {
            console.log("---after compare--- ");
        }        
    });
```

But when I am comparing the scroll value then sometimes scroll value skip some value.

**My scroll values(in console):**

```
1.scroll value----> 423
1.window height---> 431
2.scroll value----> 427
2.window height---> 431
3.scroll value----> 432    
3.window height---> 431
4.scroll value----> 434
4.window height---> 431
5.scroll value----> 436
5.window height---> 431
```

If you are notice second comparison:

> 2.scroll value----> 427
>     2.window height---> 431

Not same scroll value and window height. Scroll value directly jump from **2.scroll value----> 427** to ***scroll value----> 432***. And skip 431 value of scroll. How to compare exact scroll value with window height.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
if (scroll == windowHeight) {
    console.log("---after compare--- ");
}
```

You rely on the browser that will trigger the `scroll` event on every single pixel scrolled.
In reality this is impossible because of performance reasons (consider how slow will be your code if I scroll 1000 pixels to the bottom of a page)

It's much like comparing floating point numbers. You need some constant to determine what is considered "equal":

```
var deltaScroll = 15 ;
if (scroll > windowHeight - deltaScroll && scroll < windowHeight + deltaScroll) {
    console.log("---after compare--- ");
}
```

For better results you can base `deltaScroll` on windowHeight, e.g. 5% of it:

```
var deltaScroll = windowHeight / 20
```

(try different values to find the best one)

Comment: Why the downvote? I find this a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: @AI.G. Actually this is good approach but I want to send ajax call after satisfy the condition only once time. But in this condition generate multiple ajax call under in "if" condition.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to track whether the user scrolled past a certain point and react to the "event".

```
var wasOnfirstPage = true; // scroll < height

$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var isOnFirstPage = scroll < windowHeight; // current state

    if (wasOnFirstPage && !isOnFirstPage) {
        console.log("user scrolled fully past first page");
    }
    else if (!wasOnFirstPage && isOnFirstPage) {
        console.log("user scrolled back up");
    }

    wasOnFirstPage = isOnFirstPage;
});
```

That way, not only does it not matter that the value changes by more than one pixel, you also detect the direction of the scrolling.

Comment: you can see https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-infinite-scroll-pagination--wp-24873. Because i want to generate ajax call for the pagination. Here is a some condition for this . $(window).scroll(function(){
                    if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
                          // run our call for pagination
                    }
            });

Comment: The tutorial detects scrolling to the very end of the page, which will work because you can't scroll past it. The code you posted doesn't attempt to do that, and your questions wasn't about scrolling to the end either.

Comment: Could you suggest me some jquery or javascript for pagination with ajax call to append the page.

Answer (score 0):

> 1.**old** scroll value----> 423
>
> 1.window height---> 431
>
> 2.**new** scroll value----> 427
>
> 2.window height---> 431

You can't, because it depends on the speed of the user's scroll (i.e. how many lines of text the page should scroll).

But, you can keep track of the last value of the scroll, and check if the height of the window is between the last value and the new value of the scroll. Hope it helps

Comment: Yes, I also tried this one. But I need to compare only exact value Because condition should satisfy only once time.